# Unable to use bpamodel cmdlet in powershell 5

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I'm trying to use the best practices module in powershell, but both the invoke and get -BpaModel are not recognized.  I also tried to use Import-module BestPractices, but it says no valid file was found in the module directory.  This is in powershell 5 running on windows 7 .  Any idea what i'm missing and why it's missing to begin with?   Could this be a permission issue?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think BPA is included with Windows 7.  You may be able to [find and install it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15556), but most documentation says it's for Server 2008 R2 only.  BPA also has a prerequisite of the [Microsoft Baseline Configuration Analyzer 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16475), so that may also be needed.  Even then, those PowerShell cmdlets might just not work on Windows 7.

Comment: That has all the information I needed to figure this out, as it explains everything going on. You should put it as an answer by the way.

Comment: After looking at your links,  I wonder if we are looking at the same bestpractice module, because these don't seem to refer to powershell.

Comment: Nevermind. I think you're right.  Did some more digging.  Just to clarify, this applies to validation of powershell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Best Practices Analyzer (BPA) is a server management tool that is available in Windows Server 2012 R2, 2012, and 2008 R2. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831400.aspx)

According to the [latest documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/bestpractices/invoke-bpamodel) I can find, the cmdlets will only be available on machines that have the BPA installed, quoting "Get-BPAModel":

> SYNOPSIS -
> Retrieves and displays the list of BPA models *installed on the system*.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the author's question.  You are not even sure, if BPA cannot cannot be installed on Windows 7, and listing what it does support isn't really an answer to the question.  If your answer is BpA doesn't support Windows 7, say that, if you have verified that's the case.

Comment: @Ramhound - don't agree this time :), the author asks why it is missing, and I explain because it is a server management tool.  The question isn't whether BPA is supported on Windows 7, but why those cmdlets are "missing".  It's missing because it isn't included with Windows 7 by default, unlike the server OS versions quoted.

Comment: I presume this answer isn't correct

Comment: If you are not sure of something either confirm it, for the benefits of   everyone who actually would like to know, don't even mention it.  Authorative answers are extremely easy to write, you do a Google of search, and you interpret and state a decisive statement.  "I'd presume you could get the BPA cmdlets on Windows 7", isn't worth the paper, it's not written on....with all due respect